# Extract the first word of string in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    Case_number,
    Week_number,
    (LEFT(case.SUB, charindex(' ', case.SUB) - 1)) 
     AS CASE,
 and so on ....
```

Can anyone help me to extract the word before the space in CASE column? The above syntax is not working. I am not super good with SQL queries, help would be really appreciated.

Comment: what is there in `SUB_TYPE`?

Comment: Why is MySQL tagged? MySQL doenst support the function charindex..

Comment: Is it Oracle or MySQL?

Comment: what you want to get from RAJ KIRAN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LOCATE() function with the SUBSTR() one.

For instance :

```
SELECT Machine_number, Week_number, 
SUBSTR( machine_dim.SUB_TYPE, 1, LOCATE(' ' ,machine_dim.SUB_TYPE)) AS Machine_type
```

To sort also records with full word without space, use the following form :

```
SELECT Machine_number, Week_number, 
CASE LOCATE(' ',machine_dim.SUB_TYPE) 
    WHEN 0 THEN machine_dim.SUB_TYPE 
    ELSE SUBSTR( machine_dim.SUB_TYPE, 1, LOCATE(' ' ,machine_dim.SUB_TYPE)) 
END AS Machine_type
```

Note that this syntax may not be supported with some SGBD (SQL Server, Firebird for instance).

Hope this helps

Comment: I have updated the answer with the form to also include records without space

Answer (score 4):

In Sql Server :

```
       DECLARE @text varchar(100)='Why is MySQL tagged'
       SELECT left(@text,charindex(' ',@text))

       Output :
               Why
```

Answer (score 0):

IN Standard SQL, It can be achieved using below example.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING("RAJ KIRAN", 1, POSITION(" " IN "RAJ KIRAN")) AS OutputString;
```

Replace hard coded value "RAJ KIRAN" with column Name.
Thanks